# AWS FIFO DLQ redrive via AWS console or other mechanism

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sqs-fifo

"Start DLQ redrive" is disabled for FIFO DLQ in AWS console and AWS documentation is clear AWS wouldn't support it for FIFO queue. Question is what are my options now , Will AWS cli be able to support that?, Please provide me any other alternatives or suggestions.